# Homotopical characterization of CW complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be a compact metrizable topological space of covering dimension $n\leq 3$.

Is it possible to give a necessary and sufficient condition for $X$ to be a CW complex in terms of the homotopy types of the neighbourhoods of subspaces of $X$?

If $n=1$ I think one can require that each point $x\in X$ has a contractible open neighbourhood $U$ such that $U\setminus \{x\}$ has finitely many connected components, and that for all but finitely many $x\in X$ there is a contractible open neighbourhood $U$ such that $U\setminus \{x\}$ has exactly two connected components.

Bing's theorem says that a compact connected locally connected Hausdorff space $M$ with more than one point is homeomorphic to $S^2$ provided that no embedded $S^0$ separates $M$ and any embedded $S^1$ separates $M$. This could be helpful but I am not sure.

Comment: A special case is whether it is possible to give a local homotopical characterization of 3-manifolds. This is an open question. The version with the strongest possible hypotheses is the [Bing-Borsuk conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing–Borsuk_conjecture), which is probably false in dimension $\geqslant 4$ and open in dimension 3. In particular, it would give a new proof of the Poincaré conjecture.